# Allow ip address / machine name accessible from remote conneciton

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I've installed a ipfs file server and can access it locally on port 8080 but cannot access it via machine name or ip address locally. so `http://localhost:8080` connects but `http://<IP_ADDRESS_OF_MACHINE>:8080` does not connect (on Chrome 'refused to connect.' message displayed).

netstat -tlpn returns :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26147/ipfs
```

Should there also be entry to indicate that port is accessible via machine name or IP address ? :

```
tcp        0      0 <IP_ADDRESS_OF_MACHINE>:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26147/ipfs
```

If so can this be configured via iptables ?

Comment: `http://:8080/` is not a valid URI.  The host is a mandatory part of the authority string.

Comment: @user4556274 that was a typo and has been fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ipfs issue and required to change configuration. Specifically update

~/.ipfs/config with :

"Gateway": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080"

instead of:

"Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080"